# How to interpret forestplot with pymc on standard devisions of two groups

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, python, pymc

I'm using pyMC3 to do Bayesian estimation supersedes the t test (BEST) and I was wondering how to actually interpret this result. I see both groups have significantly different stds because the bar plot doesn't cross over zero. But why am I having negative std? I thought it's impossible to get negative std given the std formula. How do you actually interpret this result? 
I followed [this example](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/BEST.html) to do BEST in pyMC3.

Thanks!

[image]